# Setting hidden field value with Jquery $('#id').attr("value", 'val'); not working in IE

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

I noticed that IE doesnt fill the value of a hidden field, using the code below, while Chrome and FF have no problem with this.

```
$('#id').attr("value", 'val');
```

I tried a few other things like `.setAttribute` or `.val() = "val";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass value to [**val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) jquery function,

```
$('#id').val("your value");
```

Comment: Y wouldn't it work when the OP tried setting it with .attr() .. Using  .attr() sets the value using setAttribute right ?

Comment: look it the syntax he used ".val() = "val";

Comment: yup that is wrong way .. But how abt $('#id').attr("value", 'val');

Comment: @Adil... Setting value this way will work.. I was wondering if you know why the OP's code does not work :)

Comment: @Sushanth can guess may me more code could reveal the secret.

Comment: the code from jsfiddle also works for my IE, still when i test this out in a page and check the source.. the value of the hidden field is not set.

Comment: I tested it in Chrome with the inspect element and it was set. I guess viewing the source was not the smart thing to do.. looks like it doesn't update. Thanks allot for your help :)